# SQL database differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I have there 2 codes on how to connect to SQL Server 2005 database. **code 1** are using Dataset, and Dataadapter, **code 2**, didn't used neither. Can anyone please help me explain what is the differences and advatages/disadvantages on both programs..thankz

**code1**

```
//create connection, dataset, dataadapter
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
DataSet ds1;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
```

int MaxRows = 0; //hold how many rows in the dataset
int inc = 0; //change the current Row number
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
      ds1 = new DataSet();
      //setting the connection string
      con.ConnectionString  = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
      con.Open();

```
 //create object for 'da' variable
 string sql = "SELECT * From tblOutbox";
 da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

 da.Fill(ds1, "tblOutbox");
 NavigateRecords();
 //get the number of rows in DataSet
 MaxRows = ds1.Tables["tblOutbox"].Rows.Count;

 con.Close();
```

}

**code 2:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

//command queries
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
//cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblSend (ip, msg, date) SELECT ip, msg, date FROM tblOutbox";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open(); //open con
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute query
sqlConnection1.Close(); //close con

Answer (score 2):

In the first code you are trying to fetch a resultset from database using [dataadpater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx) and then filling a dataset with the [fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill.aspx) method of dataadapter.

In the second one you are inserting details to a table using [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method of [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object.

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 is a fetch (hence the dataset which is a data storage object) and code 2 simply runs a command (an insert) into the dbase.  However the cmd.CommandText() is commented (and thus isn't set) so that code will actually throw an exception.

EDIT: Have a look here:
[ADO.Net 2.0 Documentation MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

Comment: Aaa, that was my mistakes, it was not commented, and yes it doing queries for 'insert into'. But what is the different from the term of query? code 1 was bind with ' System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()' method, while code2 using ' System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' code??

Answer (score 1):

The first one gets something from the database, it's a `select`. The second one does nothing but if the cmd.CommandText is uncommented it performs an `insert`. They are definitely not examples of doing the same thing in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

First one you are selecting and in the second one you are inserting :)

[Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), and [Dataadapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx) are used to fetch data from database .

Dataadapter act as a bridge between database and dataset .

In your second code says that its for insertion of your data to database.

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) says how many rows are affected .

Comment: Ok , thank you all for reply. But if i wanna cameout with a program, which approach should i used? The code 2 seems much more shorter, if looked at the way how the database is connected!!